# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError for class belonging to user-defined jar in JBOSS 7 EAP

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x

```
02:35:43,076 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (default task-8) Failed to define class com.karthik.db.jpub.mapping.ObjUser in Module "deployment.CVRepo.war:main" from Service M
odule Loader: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link com/karthik/db/jpub/mapping/ObjUser (Module "deployment.CVRepo.war:main" from Service Module Loader): oracle/sql/ORAData
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:446)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:274)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:78)
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:605)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)
```

Here, ObjUser class belongs to Data.jar. Data.jar exists in WEB-INF/lib folder of CVRepo.war
1) What is causing this error even though the jar - data.jar that contains the class - ObjUser.class is packaged in CVRepo.war.
 **2) Should external jars(data.jar) be removed from WEB-INF/lib folder of WAR and be added as module and be referenced in  jboss-deployment.xml of WAR in JBOSS 7?**

Answer (score 0):

NoClassDefFoundError typically are thrown because the class is not in the classpath, which could be because of the packaging of the application or the classloader isolation settings specified. Look at the Tattletale Report: Class Location to locate where it is packaged and compare to the isolation settings & Java EE classpath defined for the particular deployment type.

Note: if the class does not exist in the application and the java source file does not list the class, decompile the class using javap or other decompiler and see if the class definition matches the source. Some IDEs can generate invalid classes when the classpath is missing classes, they could generate a class with invalid class references and if those get deployed it will cause unusual ClassNotFoundExceptions such as a class name with no package.

NoClassDefFoundError is thrown when the JVM tries to load a definition of a class and no definition can be found. NoClassDefFoundError is caused by typically a ClassNotFoundException or a ExceptionInInitializerError. After the initial ClassNotFoundException / ExceptionInInitializerError, the JVM will just throw a NoClassDefFoundError and will not show the original cause.

Review the full server.log and locate the first classloading exception

Refer the link basic Class Loading stuffs:
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Class+Loading+in+AS7

Comment: Thanks for helping me. I understand that NoClassDefFoundError typically are thrown because the class is not in the class path but the class - ObjUser is bundled inside the CVRepo.war. It exists in data.jar of WEB-INF/lib folder. So ideally it should be available in the classpath